# Trying to use go function from node using c++ wrapper gets segfault

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I am trying to call my go function from nodejs using a C++ wrapper.

```
func Decode(data *C.char) *C.char {
    buffer.Data = C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(data), 1<<30)
    ...
```

If I'm trying to simulate it from go, it works and I get the expected result.

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(testFile)
check(err)
cs := (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]))
```

However, when I'm trying it from node i get

```
unexpected fault address 0x7f21ac70ef90
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x7f21ac70ef90 pc=0x7f21ad754375]
```

node code:

```
const input = fs.readFileSync(testFile)
const output = decode(input)
```

C++ code:

```
const char *param = data.c_str();
char *g = (*Decode)(&param[0]);
```

In C++ both the parameter and result are treated as char*.

I also tried using `unsafe.sizeof(data)` to use instead of `1<<30`, but it always returns 8.

Before this I was passing the filename and reading it in go and everything worked, however I want to read it in node.

Comment: The call `buffer.Data = C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer(data), 1<<30)` tries to copy 2^30 bytes from `data` into an allocated buffer. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: That was the problem, I added a parameter for size, thank you